# Django template tag split

Tags: django, templates, tags

I have a **url** which is generated using `{{request.get_ull_path}}`. I want to **split** and **get last part** of it using **django template tag**.

```
<a  href="{{ request.get_full_path }}">
```

**which gives me**

```
abc.me/profile/bio/
```

How can I get only last part (**bio**) using **django template tag**? Or do I have to write **custom template tag**?

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352455/obtain-the-first-part-of-an-url-from-django-template. However, @Jbertrand is correct with his logic.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this kind of thing in a template. Django intentionally discourage you from doing too much processing in template. You should just split before rendering the view.

See this post : [Django templates - split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317537/django-templates-split-string-to-array)